# Android HandlerThread update UI without UiHandler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, android-looper

this code works fine  and update my "TextView" and also show "Toast" 
and that is my Headache as I have tried to to pass A Runnable obj Without including my UiHandler on it as it suppose to be the bridge to update my UI Thread but my activity got updated with no single Error ?????
This not suppose to be as CustomHandlerThread should be A different thread

why this happen ?

> My Activity

public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
Runnable task;
@BindView(R.id.send_test_message)
Button send_test_message;
private Handler mUiHandler = new Handler();
private MyWorkerThread mWorkerThread;

@Override
public void initViews() {

}

@Override
public void attachViewsListeners() {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    task = new Runnable() { ///this is normally work I have no problem with 
                            ///that 
        @Override
        public void run() {

                mUiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        send_test_message.setText("Change--->1");
                    }
                });

            }


    };


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mWorkerThread = new MyWorkerThread("myWorkerThread");
    mWorkerThread.start();
    mWorkerThread.prepareHandler();
    mWorkerThread.postTask(task);

    mWorkerThread.postTask(new Runnable() {  /// why this task work with no 
                                            ///error  ?
        @Override
        public void run() {
            send_test_message.setText("Change--->2");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mWorkerThread.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

> my HandlerThread

```
//MyWorkerThread.java
public class MyWorkerThread extends HandlerThread {

    Handler mWorkerHandler;

    public MyWorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void postTask(Runnable task) {
        mWorkerHandler.post(task);
    }

    public void prepareHandler() {

    mWorkerHandler = new Handler(getLooper());

Log.e("MyWorkerThread--->",Looper.myLooper().getThread().getName()); //-->main
Log.e("MyWorkerThread--->",getLooper().getThread().getName());//-->//myWorkerThread
Log.e("MyWorkerThread--->",Thread.currentThread().getName()); //-->main

    }
}
```

I followed this [link](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/) as A Referance

is My thread running on the MainThread or getLooper() intialize my 
 HandlerThread with MainThread Looper ,is those log message are true

### please illuminate me

Answer (score 0):

> After fill day of debugging i Found out That if i post A Runnable to my
>   mWorkerThread with sleep() as here i got " Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."
>   as should be.. but until I know why it not works without it
>   I wish it would help some one.

```
   try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                        send_test_message.setText("Change--->");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```